# Magento 2.3.5-P2 : Method 'getExtensionAttributes' must be overridden in the interfaces

Tags: extension-attributes

Recently we upgraded magento version from **2.3.2** to **2.3.5-p2**. We are getting error while placing an order after update. In 2.3.2 version there is no issue.

```
Error : 
report.CRITICAL: Method 'getExtensionAttributes' must be overridden in the interfaces which extend 'Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface'. Concrete return type must be specified. Please fix :\Namespace\Modulename\Api\Data\PaymentInterface {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Method 'getExtensionAttributes' must be overridden in the interfaces which extend 'Magento\\Framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataInterface'. Concrete return type must be specified.



 Please fix :\\Namespace\\Modulename\\Api\\Data\\PaymentInterface at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Magento235\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Api\\ExtensionAttributesFactory.php:68)"} []
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Did you set the preference of the `PaymentInterface` to a concrete class in `etc/di.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and solved it by using the full name of the class implementing ExtensibleDataInterface, and not the shorthand with a use statement.